# MSOpenTech redis with redis-sharp client

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, redis

I built MSOpenTech redis and installed it as a service on Windows 7.  Using the cli it appears to be working great.  So then I needed a client that was as simple as possible and was compatible with .NET 3.5 so I picked redis-sharp.  It built just fine (VS 2010), and it connects to the redis server on localhost port 6379 as is normal.  But with the very first "r.Set("foo", "bar")" it fails.  More accurately, it sets key "foo" to "3" instead of bar and then all other commands fail after that.  I then thought I would isolate the client vs. the server, but trying to connect to another server running redis failed even though I can ping it.

I have two questions: 1) Is there a known redis open-source client for C# that can run on .NET 3.5 (I know redis-sharp is supposed to be that client)? 2) Is MSOpenTech redis stable and have a known client that works with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed the problem was with redis-sharp.  This doesn't mean it doesn't work with other certain configurations, but with .NET 3.5 it certainly did not.  I used hiredis that is packaged with MSOpenTech redis source.  It is c-code and took some work to get the libraries to link, but once it built it has worked well.  As far as I know for my second question MSOpenTech redis appears stable.  It was just the redis-sharp client.  Perhaps there was a protocol change at some point, as there is clearly a problem with the data being sent by redis-sharp over the socket (for my version of items).

I also resolved why I couldn't talk to my remote redis server on linux.  It was the "bind" configuration option that was set to localhost.  That one was easy.

Comment: Please flag your own answer as the correct answer. Good you got it solved.